# Stream generate until a limit but only matching a predicate

Tags: java, java-stream

How do I generate a list using Stream of exactly 100 elements. But all elements in the list should match a predicate.

Testcode:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Stream;


public class Main {
    // My predicate
    public static Predicate<Integer> isBig() {
        return p -> p > 10;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        Stream.generate(new Random()::nextInt)
                .limit(100)
                //???????
                .forEach(a -> list.add(a));

        // Always needs to be 100
        System.out.println(list.size());
    }
}
```

I could do this with a while loop and a counter (`while counter < 100`). In the while loop I then would create random Integers, and only add the to a specific list and increase the counter when an element matches the predicate.

But this is not efficient and it needs to be done with streams.

PseudoCode:

```
 Stream.generate(new Random()::nextInt)
                .limit(100)
                .onlyAddIfMatches(isBig())
                .forEach(a -> list.add(a));
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Put a `filter` before the `limit`.

Comment: What exactly is your bias for the elements in the Stream? What are you trying to filter by?

Comment: `stream.filter(predicate::test).limit(100).collect(Collectors.toList());` or something like that.  (Just to show an example of the code that @Slaw was referencing.)

Comment: @BeUndead Using a filter does not make the list size 100 always.

Comment: Correct.  Using the 'limit' that I also included does though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
List<Integer> list = Stream.generate(new Random()::nextInt)
                .filter(p -> p > 10)
                .limit(100).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or like this one:

```
public class Main {

    private static boolean isBig(Integer input) {
        return input > 10;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Integer> list = Stream.generate(new Random()::nextInt)
                .filter(Main::isBig)
                .limit(100).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: I used your code, but the size of the list when using filter is not 100. The size must always be 100. So it needs to keep filling matching integers until it got to 100.

Comment: I've just run it it is exactly 100.

Comment: My bad, I putted limit before filter.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:**

Do **not** use the `filter` method on a stream with a pseudo-random-number source if you can do what ever you want to do differently.

If you do you will at best run into performance drops and at worst into a hanging program.

This is because if you just take random numbers and filter them you will most probably gennerate more numbers than you need.
For example if you want 100 even random numbers you will on average need to generate 200 random numbers.

The worst case comes into play if the PRNG has a bad seed and cycles only through numbers that does not match the predicate, so you can never collect the requiered amount of numbers.

To conclude: If you need `n` random numbers that meet a certain predicate (for example positive) the (if possible) just create `n` random numbers and map the ones that do not match the predicate to one that matches (for example take the absolute value of the negative numbers to only have positive numbers).

**Original answer**

If you want to filter a stream just use the method `filter`:
like

```java
Random r = new Random();
List<Integer> list = Stream.generate(() -> r.nextInt())
    .filter(n -> n > 0) // filter for positive numbers
    .filter(n -> n % 2 == 0) // filter for even
    .limit(10)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But you should be cousious about your stream source. If you use a PRNG you should try to limit the range of numbers that are generated.

For example the above example can be achived with

```
Random r = new Random();
List<Integer> list = Stream.generate(() -> r.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE/2) * 2)
    .limit(10)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and is to be preferred, because the first example could run into a cycle of pseudo-random-numbers that never meet the requirements.

So as a general rule. If you deal with a random source, try to **create** from the input the numbers you want and not filter the random input.

Comment: I used your code, but the size of the list when using filter is not 100. The size must always be 100. So it needs to keep filling matching integers until it got to 100.

Comment: That is because I use 10 as a limiting value just as an example. Just change the argument for the `limit` method to what ever you want.

Comment: @O'Niel Also please read the whole answer I highly disregard the use of a random number source combined with an later filtering of the random numbers.

Comment: @O'Niel You may also want to consider using [`Random#ints(int,int,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#ints(long,int,int)), though that method returns an `IntStream` instead of a `Stream<Integer>`.